# Convert string to int in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column with names like:

```
Ernest Hemingway
Jackson Pollock
```

I want to convert them to numbers and store them in an INT field. Maybe getting the position of each letter in the alphabet or something like this, resulting a number:

```
23764283456
23984623746
```

Is there any function to do something like this? I don't mind the length of the INT or if the result is one number or another. The important thing is that every time I apply the function to a name, the result is the same.

Thanks!

Comment: The numbers that you have specified -- such as 23,764,283,456 -- are too long for an `int` field in MySQL.  Hence your question is a bit unclear.  I would probably suggest, though, that you research hashing.  You might also want to explain why you want to do this.

Comment: What do you want to do with the number? Because your requirement can be solved by converting every input to the number `1`.

Comment: Thanks! I want to do this because I need to name the files for the images of the persons in my DB, and the best way is to transform the name of the person into a number, and name the file with this number as 34823793642.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`crc32('Ernest Hemingway');`

will always give you `2479642411`

Comment: Some inputs would produce A-F characters in the result.

Comment: @GrasDouble for example ??

Comment: Though, half of the results will be negative on 32-bit platforms, so you may have to convert to an absolute value: `abs(crc32('foobar'))`. There will be discrepancies between and 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

Comment: @GrasDouble You are abso-bloody-lutey right. But, I just answered the question as the OP just wanted a consistent conversion of the string to a numeric value.

Comment: `SELECT abs(crc32(name)) FROM person` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as @Gordon_Linoff said in the comments large number can't be store on filed of type `int`

but I will show you how to convert string to the ascii of the chars

you can use `HEX`

```
SELECT HEX('test')
+-------------+
| HEX('test') |
+-------------+
| 74657374    |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-way hash, but with an important concern: the integer should be representable on the platform.

PHP code, assuming 32-bit compatibility is desired:

```
$hash = sha1('Ernest Hemingway');

// last 6 characters, represent 3 bytes
$hash = substr($hash, -6);

$result = hexdec($hash); // integer: 1331016
```

Keep in mind this has a very low entropy: 2^24 = 16777216 possibilities

4 bytes is too large, because signed/unsigned integer discrepancies would lead to float with some inputs, and floats really can't be casted to integers with perfect determinism.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT field,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num
FROM table
ORDER BY num;